# Automorphisms of the field of rational functions $\Bbb C(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, rational-functions, automorphism-group

Given the field of rational functions $\Bbb C(t)$, how do we show that a certain function defines an automorphism. I ask because I read here https://nptel.ac.in/courses/111101001/downloads/problemset8.pdf. That $\sigma(t)=wt$, defines an automorphism but automorphisms must be isomorphisms which implies that $\sigma(u*v)=\sigma(u)*\sigma(v)$. But it seems to me $\sigma(uv)=wuv\neq w^2 uv=\sigma(u)\sigma(v)$.

What I think might be the case :

We're dealing with $\Bbb C(t)=\{\tfrac{f(t)}{g(t)}|f,g \in \Bbb C[x], g(t) \neq0 \}$.

So we should then apply our element as follows :

$\sigma(\tfrac{f(t)}{g(t)})=\tfrac{f(\sigma(t))}{g(\sigma(t))}=\tfrac{f(wt)}{g(wt)}$.

But then in terms of showing this is an automorphism , I'm not sure how to proceed , $f,g$ are just arbitrary functions so I don't understand how could manipulate such functions to show $\sigma(\tfrac{f(t)}{g(t)}\tfrac{h(t)}{k(t)})=\sigma(\tfrac{f(t)}{g(t)})\sigma(\tfrac{h(t)}{k(t)})$.

Could anyone clarify this point for me ?

Note: The link isn't from a course I'm in , I just found it while searching for information on Galois theory.

Comment: You have only been given one value of $\sigma$. Namely $\sigma(t)=1/t$. You need to extend this to a full definition such that the extension is an automorphism. Try to see what would be the value of $\sigma$ at some particular cases. For example $\sigma(t^n)$, or $\sigma(p(t))$ for $p$ a polynomial. Then try to prove that you will need to have $\sigma(r(t))=r(1/t)$ for any rational function $r$.

Comment: @user647486 It was actually supposed to be $\sigma(t)=wt$, but I'm sure your comment still stands. But I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean Shouldn't we always have that $\sigma(r(t))=r(1/t)$, simply by the fact that it will always act on the indeterminate t in r(t). Or is what you mean that we must show that we must show it acts on the intederminate t but keeps the ground field $\Bbb C$ fixed ?

Comment: In both cases you are being given only one value of each automorphism: $\sigma(t)=wt$ and $\tau(t)=1/t$. Yes, this implies that $\tau(r(t))=r(1/t)$, which follows from the properties that an automorphism must satisfy. Likewise $\sigma(r(t))=r(wt)$, instead of multiplication by $w$, as in $wr(t)$.

Comment: Yes, $\sigma(r(t))=r(wt)$. A nitpick: it was left out from the description that rules like $\sigma(t)=1/t$ and $\sigma(t)=wt$ define a unique $\Bbb{C}$-automorphism of $\Bbb{C}(t)$. This means that $\sigma(z)=z$ for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$. Anyway, if $\sigma(t)=wt$ then $\sigma(t^2)=(\sigma(t))^2=w^2t^2$ et cetera.

Comment: In other words, $t$ is not an arbitrary element of the field $\Bbb{C}(t)$. It is the prescribed transcendetal element, a generator of the extension $\Bbb{C}(t)/\Bbb{C}$. What's going on here is not at all unlike the fact that a $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$ is fully determined once you specify $\sigma(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$. A difference here is that $t$ is not algebraic. So its image $\sigma(t)=q\in\Bbb{C}(t)$ is only constrained by the fact that we must have $\Bbb{C}(t)=\Bbb{C}(q)$ (for otherwise the resulting mapping won't be bijective). That's for the next lecture!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $w$ is a non-zero complex number.

The definition of $\sigma$ means that $$\sigma(f)=f\circ\psi,$$where $$\psi(t)=wt.$$That should make it clear that $\sigma(f+g)=\sigma(f)+\sigma(g)$, etc.